# Run a function after returning response

Tags: php, curl, pthreads, slim-3

I have an API created with Slim 3.

In it I have some curl execution such as sending Push notification to a user.

I want send response to requester then execute curl or any other function.

I read about Threads in `PHP` and use `pthreads-polyfill` but it sends response after finishing Thread.

Sample tested code:

```
 $app->get('/test', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    PushController::publish("1111111", "HELLO");
    $result =  'OK';

    return $response->getBody()->write($result)->withStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: I don't know if there is way to do it after the response (AFAIK no). I always use a third party queue service, like Amazon SQS or RabbitMQ for that purpose

Comment: Try to use either Queue jobs or CRON jobs. CRON jobs are simpler to implement. Redis can be used to implement queuing system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to do, and threading is not the answer. 
One solution is to call a script from the main one, as you mentioned.
A more elegant one imho, is to call [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) . It will return the answer to the requester and continue to execute the script. Unfortunately this function is only available with PHP-FPM. Which is the industry standard by now but does not necessarily comes as default when you install a LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement two solutions may suite

1. Queue
2. Cron

**Redis** can be used as queuing server. For that you need to install redis server on your system. There is php implementation of [predis](https://redis.io/) for Redis. For more details about Redis you can read it in [Redis official site](https://redis.io/). **Beanstalkd** can also used as Queuing server.

To learn, how to create cron jobs you can refer the exisitng [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)